# SQL Table Paging PERFORMANCE ...is EF4 + Linq SKIP +TAKE equal in performance than using TSQL params to request "paging" on a SQL Table?

Tags: t-sql, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

If I want to retrieve records from 20 to 39, or from 40 to 59 from an MSSQL Table.

Since I'm using MVC and EF4, is performance the same if I just do a Linq query and Skip() and Take() procedure to request paging ....or is it better to do it on a GetList() Stored Procedure itself?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you execute this linq query:

```
var data = context.Posts.OrderBy(p => p.Id).Skip(20).Take(20).ToList();
```

It will produce this SQL:

```
SELECT TOP (20) 
  [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
  [Extent1].[Text] AS [Text]
FROM ( SELECT 
         [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
         [Extent1].[Text] AS [Text], 
         row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC) AS [row_number]
    FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[row_number] > 20
ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] ASC
```

It is not such nice like custom SQL you would write in your stored procedure but in the meaning of performance it is the same. Pagining  is done on database.

Comment: To confirm, you are stating that the LINQ query above will produce a result with exactly the same performance as if we were using the SQL Query above ...is that right?

Comment: Yes. The linq query above is executed as SQL above.