# SQL Server 2005 Combine and paginate two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-4

I have two tables containing data that are essentially headline lists from different sources. This is being done in MVC 3 (EF available) with SQL Server 2005.

Table 1: date - title - id

Table 2: date - title - id

What I would like to try to do is combine these into a single master list that can be

- Paginated for browsing
- Supports date based ranges for querying which can then be browsed.

Currently the paginating is difficult as the number of articles from each source in any set of X is varied by the update frequency of that source.

If this possible to do with a View or using Union All? There are about 300,000 rows covering about 15 years worth of headlines. Is there a better way I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this but combining a union with skip and take should work.

MSDN has an example of the union, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896299.aspx, I guess you'll want apply your date range filter to each part.

There's a SO answer here [SQL Table Paging PERFORMANCE ...is EF4 + Linq SKIP +TAKE equal in performance than using TSQL params to request "paging" on a SQL Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345939/sql-table-paging-performance-is-ef4-linq-skip-take-equal-in-performance-th) that talks about skip and take as well as the performance.

You could probably make things easier for your self by combining the data from tables 1&2 into one with a source field if you like.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Got this working both in EF as well as straight SQL.  Just what I needed.