# LINQ to SQL . how to select all record using .take()

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

```
var result=(from refridgerators in context.A                                               
                                     group refridgerators by new { refridgerators.Id, refridgerators.Name } into gr
                                     select new DAO<String>
                                     {
                                         Key = gr.Key.Name,
                                         Count = gr.Count()
                                     }).OrderByDescending(k => k.Count).Take(numberOfRecords).ToList();
```

This is my linq to sql query this is working perfectly fine.

this shows top 5 records (sorted by their count)  if i pass numberOfRecords =5.

now my problem is i don`t want to modify query. so what should i do in above query to show all records. This is in relation with my requirement i want to use same query to show all refridgerators and Top 5 , top 10 refridgerators.

I am not sure if it is possible using LINQ. but i guess there must be something related to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the right solution has already been posted by Tim, still I want your attention to the simpler solution, if suits to your requirement.
Add one more if condition at the top of this query.

```
if(allRecordRequired)
{
  numberOfRecords = 2000000;
}
```

Leave your query as it is.

Comment: I will go with this as my count will never  exceed this limit so i think for time being it suits my condition

Comment: An unsatisfying solution, is there no way to actually specify 'all'?

Answer (score 8):

So this post is very old, I know, but my solution is not provided (maybe someone wants to achieve the same after 2 years, like me):

You could create your own extension-method that also works with linq 2 sql. Example:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> TakeIfNotNull<TResult>(this IEnumerable<TResult> source, int? count)
    {
        return !count.HasValue ? source : source.Take(count.Value);
    } 
}
```

this takes an `int?` instead of `int` and returns either the source-enumerable if `count` is `null` else it returns the result of default `Take`-method.

So you could write like:

```
.OrderByDescending(k => k.Count).TakeIfNotNull(numberOfRecords).ToList();
```

if `numberOfCounts` is null, it'll take all records.

Answer (score 7):

I'd make numberOfRecords  a `int?` and if the value is null you should not call `Take(numberOfRecords)`

```
var result = (from refridgerators in context.A
              group refridgerators by new { refridgerators.Id, refridgerators.Name } into gr
              select new DAO<String>
              {
                 Key = gr.Key.Name,
                 Count = gr.Count()
              }).OrderByDescending(k => k.Count);

if(numberOfRecords.HasValue)
    result = result.Take(numberOfRecords.Value);

return result.ToList();
```

I know it changes your query a little bit but I believe it is pretty acceptable, adding a `numberOfRecords` of a super high value adds an overheard to your query which isn't useful in your case.

Comment: Thanks. this post was helpful. this was a lot similar to answer given by Tim Schmelter. and i used the null value too..

Comment: Indeed the answer is very similar, though I personally don't like returning an IEnumerable<T> that hasn't been executed, since it can get hard to figure where the execution is done when your code gets bigger.

Comment: I tried this and had an issue with OrderByDescending() returning a different type than Take(), making it so that `result` couldn't be reassigned.

I fixed it by adding `.TakeWhile(t => true)` after `OrderByDescending(k => k.Count)`

Answer (score 6):

I would simply don't add the `Take` to the query but to the code where you consume this query.

So for example:

```
public static IEnumerable<DAO> GetRefrigerators()
{
    var query = from refridgerators in context.A                                               
                group refridgerators by new { refridgerators.Id, refridgerators.Name } into gr
                select new DAO<String>
                {
                     Key = gr.Key.Name,
                     Count = gr.Count()
                };
    return query.OrderByDescending(k => k.Count);
}
```

Now you can either use:

```
var refrigerators = GetRefrigerators().Take(5).ToList();
```

or

```
var refrigerators = GetRefrigerators().Take(10).ToList();
```

or

```
var refrigerators = GetRefrigerators().ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful. so what you meant to say is i have to select all records and then take final 5,10 . so it would be performance over head. i followed this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345939/sql-table-paging-performance-is-ef4-linq-skip-take-equal-in-performance-th

Comment: @user2010571: there is no performance overhead since all methods use deferred execution. The query gets executed at the final `ToList`. So the `Take(10)` will be translated to sql and executed in database. Note that `GetRefrigerators().ToList()` will load *all* records into a `List<T>` which can hurt your memory (in future).

Comment: Splitting the original query into two functions is an extra work, which might not be necessary.

Comment: @themefield: what kind of extra work you mean? There is only one method `GetRefrigerators` which returns the query, so appending `Take` if desired is not really extra work. In terms of performance there is no impact at all. But the method itself is not the crucial point of this answer. Just build the query first that would return all records, but DON'T append `ToList`,`ToArray`,`ToDictionary` or any other method that executes the query. Then append `Take(n)` if you want only the first n-records. Then you're free to use i.e. `ToList` to get the result. Only this will execute the query.

Answer (score 2):

Pass a huge number to your method.A number that is equal (at least) or bigger than the items count.That should give you all records.

Comment: Thank you, one thing i want to ask that so it means there is nothing default in take() which selects all the records

Comment: @user2010571 yes, that's why the name of the method is Take not Select.

Answer (score -1):

```
.Take(numberOfRecords ?? refridgerators.Count)
```

p.s. numberOfRecords should be nullable